# How can I ignore an SSL certificate error in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to ignore an SSL certificate error to do some UAT testing internally at our company for a Silverlight application.  The client calls a resource that's using a self-signed certificate, and for a bunch of institutional reasons, simply adding that cert to the machines of those wishing to test it isn't feasible.

In my Windows service, I can simply use:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

That does not appear to exist in Silverlight 5.  How can I ignore the certificate errors in the Silverlight client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Simple as that. You will need to find another solution. The user acceptance test should include scenarios that are likely to occur in real life, so I don't see why adding a cert if you need it in the production environment is not possible. Anyway, maybe your service could be reached by non-secured basic http in your inhouse testing scenario?

Comment: Can you provide any documentation to support that it's not possible, and/or why?

Comment: It's hard to come by documentation stating what is _not_ possible, but Silverlight has a pretty strict security model, this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx) might be a good start for reading.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer in lieu of anything better, do wish there was something a little more concrete on it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (just at develop environment is ) :

1.Trust certificate install it on Trusted Root.

2. Set at Etc/Hosts  IP - Name issued to certificate.

That don't allow you to ignore certificate, but do that your computer validate it right.

Comment: Usually allow to work, if a self-signed certificate is used.